# Custom Modules / Components can't save HTML

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I have a problem, with my custom components and modules. In the form XML i created this field

```
<field name="bio" type="editor" height="250" label="Biography"
            description="Intro To The Artist"  buttons="true" />
```

Now the data loads correctly from the DB. 
I output the Wyswig editor and the correct html with this code in the view `$this->form->getInput('bio');`
However when I save, the form. everything is saved as expected except, all html is stripped.

I don't know where this usually happens, even when I add the XML to a module (the module takes care of all the rendering usually). All displays fine, but the HTML get's stripped.

The Joomla wiki seems incomplete on and I can't find helpful information on how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was found on google groups. I needed to add `filter="safehtml"` to the field

```
<field name="bio" type="editor" height="250" label="Biography" filter="safehtml" 
            description="Intro To The Artist"  buttons="true" />
```

I believe this is Joomla 1.6 specific, also another setting might be `filter="raw"`

Comment: You are right, there is a filter 'raw' for things like javascript.. this article includes all the filter options:
http://joomla-answers.blogspot.com/2012/07/html-is-stripped-in-joomla-component.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW parameter in order to preserve the HTML.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_editor_in_a_component

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this in the next 24 hours and see if it works

Comment: Sorry this did not work on the Joomla 1.6 modules and components I worked on, thanks though

Comment: Whoops. I didn't notice the 1.6 tag. This is for 1.5 specifically.

Comment: I also tagged it joomla general as I did not know if it was 1.6 or general

Comment: You need to add 'raw' for things like javascript, for simple html 'safehtml' is preferred
http://joomla-answers.blogspot.com/2012/07/html-is-stripped-in-joomla-component.html

Answer (score 1):

To get HTML form post data you need to get this data in following way

```
$data = JRequest::getVar( 'editorName', 'defaultValue', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
```

And need to add a javascript for the view(tmpl file)

```
function submitbutton(action) {
  var form = document.adminForm;
  switch(action)
  {
  case 'save':
  case 'apply':   
   <?php
                 $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
                 echo $editor->save( 'editorName' );
         ?>
  default:
   submitform( action );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work on the Joomla 1.6 modules and components I worked on, thanks though